# How get element with jQuery from HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following HTML code:

```
<ul>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>..</li>
    <li>  
        <a href="#" class="most_views" data-sort="most_views">
            <i class="fa fa-fw"></i> 
            Most Views
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I need to update the HTML line:

```
<i class="fa fa-fw"></i>
```

with:

```
<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>
```

My jQuery code is:

```
$('a[data-sort="most_views"]').children('i').html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>');
```

This doesn't work. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addclass):

```
$('a[data-sort="most_views"]').children('i').addClass('fa-check');
```

Better to do just like this:

```
$('a[data-sort="most_views"] i').addClass('fa-check');
```

---

Using html() you're appending the element though you're doing wrong way as you're going to append `i` element inside `i` element what you mustn't want to do (I am not even caring for typo `htlm` for `html`). If you really want to replace the `i` element, you need to use:

```
// pretty sure you don't need this though
$('a[data-sort="most_views"]').html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo here:

```
$('a[data-sort="most_views"]').children('i').htlm('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>');
```

Should be:

```
$('a[data-sort="most_views"]').children('i').html('<i class="fa fa-fw fa-check"></i>');
```

Check your spelling of `html` next time.

---

(Just kidding, that isn't the answer) :P

---

Instead of `.html()`, do this:

```
$('a[data-sort="most_views"]').children('i').addClass("fa-check");
```

*Or*

```
$('.fa fa-fw')..addClass("fa-check");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it :

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".fa.fa-fw").addClass("fa-check");

})
```